# Complex POST Request In Python -- Multipart Files -- too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am attempting to POST some files and parameters as Multi-Part in the following pattern. I've tried both dict and list. `list` threw a `HTTP 415`. So I went forward with `dict`. I would like to post a few parameters as well as multiple files under a common name 'file' (along with their respective filenames).

The string parameters are working fine, the error was with the file upload

**Data passed within the multi-part dict object**

```
multipart = {
    'param1': 'paramVal1',
    'param2': 'paramVal2',
    'file': (("file1.xml", ByteIO), ("file1.xml", ByteIO)),
}
```

**POST using `python-requests`**

```
requests.post(url='http://localhost:8888/upload',files=multipart)
```

**Throws the error**

```
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 107, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 454, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 388, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 296, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 447, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 142, in _encode_files
    fn, fp, ft, fh = v
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

**Expected POST Body**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ7HAof4KTgAB21YV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file1.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


------WebKitFormBoundaryZ7HAof4KTgAB21YV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file2.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


------WebKitFormBoundaryZ7HAof4KTgAB21YV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

paramVal1
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ7HAof4KTgAB21YV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param2"

paramVal2
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ7HAof4KTgAB21YV--
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since both of the file items have the same name you can't use a dictionary, but you can use a list of tuples in the `files` parameter.
For the rest of the form data use the `data` parameter.

```
data = {
    'param1': 'paramVal1',
    'param2': 'paramVal2'
}
files = [
    ("file", ("file1.xml", open("file1.xml", "rb"), "text/xml")), 
    ("file", ("file2.xml", open("file2.xml", "rb"), "text/xml"))
]
r = requests.post(url='http://localhost:8888/upload', data=data, files=files)

print(r.request.body)
```

Request body:

```
--85d945c02ac04c9fbdcd9979e34e6d04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param2"

paramVal2
--85d945c02ac04c9fbdcd9979e34e6d04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

paramVal1
--85d945c02ac04c9fbdcd9979e34e6d04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file1.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


--85d945c02ac04c9fbdcd9979e34e6d04
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file2.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


--85d945c02ac04c9fbdcd9979e34e6d04--
```

Comment: I hope you @t.m.adam are doing well. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342861/unable-to-scrape-any-name-from-the-result-page-using-requests) might interest you. Thanks in advance.